# Finding key in python dictionary using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a dictionary streetnames and their values, as you do. Keys are strings, values are ints. 
I want to write a small piece of code that will allow me to print all streetnames that ends with "gatan" using a regular expression.

```
dictionary = {Storgatan: 46, Talgvägen: 51, Malmstigen: 8, Huvudgatan: 3...}

import re 

ends_with= 'gatan$'
test_dictionary= dictionary 

m1 = re.match(ends_with,test_dictionary)
if m1 is not None:
    print(m1)
```

This however returns the error "expected string or bytes-like object".

How do I solve this easily? Thank you

Comment: [`{k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if not k.endswith('gatan')}`](https://ideone.com/1eyJs3)

Comment: kinda unclear, define what you mean by "subtract" all streetnames

Comment: Also note the difference between `re.match` and `re.search`.  `match` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use regular expressions, you can use `re.match` while iterating over the dictionary.

```
import re

dictionary = {'Storgatan': 46, 'Talgvägen': 51, 'Malmstigen': 8, 'Huvudgatan': 3}

regex = '.*gatan$'

results = [v for k, v in dictionary.items() if re.match(regex, k)]

print(results)
```

Output:

```
[46, 3]
```

N.B: This'll be slow for large dictionaries

If you want just the key names:

```
matching_keys = [k for k in dictionary if re.match(regex, k)]
```

Comment: @duvet I've added that to my answer as well.

Comment: Did you try this `matching_keys = [k for k in dictionary if re.match(regex, k)]`

Comment: Are you sure you're doing `print(matching_keys)` and not `print(results)`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, we can use `key.endswith('gatan')` like this:

```
for key, val in dictionary.items():
    if isinstance(key, str) and not key.endswith('gatan'):
        # key not ending with `gatan`
       print(key, val)
```

If you want to create another dictionary, then we can do it in one line like this:

```
filtered_dictionary = {key: val for key, val in dictionary.items() if not key.endswith('gatan')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation of the regex [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Look for the `match` function definition. You will see that the function expects a `string` data structure there not a `dict`.